# How do I detect SVN 1.7 conflicts before SVN update?

Tags: svn

When using SVN 1.6 good old `svn merge --dry-run --revision BASE:HEAD .` would tell me.

Now with SVN 1.7 this merge won't work because the the WC is mixed revision (i.e. SVN update has not been run after commiting).

I want to know if any conflicts will occur before running the SVN update.

It seems a bit chicked and egg now.

Any ideas please?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the `--allow-mixed-revisions` flag, like this:

```
svn merge --dry-run --revision BASE:HEAD . --allow-mixed-revisions
```

This works for me, with Subversion 1.8.3.

Comment: Thanks, that looks interesting. I've just tried it and the output report tree conflicts (some new dirs and files were added to the repo from another WC). Why does SVN report these are tree conflicts, not just updates?

Comment: At least in my tests, new dirs and files added from **another WC** show up as added ("A") as expected. Keep in mind that I'm on version 1.8.3. On the other hand, new dirs and files added in the **current WC** show up as tree conflicts. I guess, it's because the WC root is at an older revision, and from that perspective it sees the existing dirs and files as obstructing the "incoming" dirs and files. Maybe this is something the svn folks could improve in the future...

Comment: Forgot to add, the tree conflicts in the latter case are bogus: dirs and files added in the current WC won't be in conflict when you actually perform the update.

Comment: Thanks for that too. That all seems to tally with what I'm observing. It's not a very satisfactory situation though!

Comment: Doesn't this work with BASE rather than the working copy?  I thought the goal was to look for conflicts with the working copy?